# Sed issue (regex syntax)

Tags: sed

I'm trying this sed to replace strings:

```
find . -type f -name "*.php" -exec sed -i "s|\!preg_match(\"\!modules\.php\!\", \\\$_SERVER\['PHP_SELF'\]) \{|\!preg_match(\"\!modules\\\.php\!\", \\\$_SERVER\['PHP_SELF'\])) \{|g" {} ";"
```

But I've an error message (error in pairing {)

I can't find the good syntax to do that. I just want to add a round bracket at the end on all files...

[edit]
Ok found it...

```
find . -type f -name "*.php" -exec sed -i "s|\!preg_match(\"\!modules\\\.php\!\", \\\$_SERVER\['PHP_SELF'\]) {|\!preg_match(\"\!modules\\\.php\!\", \\\$_SERVER\['PHP_SELF'\])) {|g" {} ";"
```

Comment: i count 3 times { and i count 1 time }  You should have 3 closing brackets

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes rather than double quotes to escape regexes and other programming language constructs that you pass on the command line from bash...

Answer (score 0):

with simple quote and assuminf $SERVER is litteral

```
sed -i 's|!preg_match("!modules\.php!", \$_SERVER\['"'"'PHP_SELF'"'"'\]) {|!preg_match("!modules\.php!", \$_SERVER\['"'"'PHP_SELF'"'"'\])) {|g'
```

I remove the !, normaly ! should pass without escape

i propose also the simplification

```
sed -i 's|\(!preg_match("!modules\.php!", \$_SERVER\['"'"'PHP_SELF'"'"'\])\) {|\1) {|g'
```